# I don’t understand how to use CSS grids to get this design

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I’m learning HTML and CSS, the problem is that I was given a design to complete. I have to use CSS grid for the overall layout. But the problem is that the height of those grid items is completely taking the height of the entire container in the **media-query** styles. I have already defined the structure of how the layout should look like with **grid-template-area** property. I don’t know how to adjust the height of the grid item to match the design. In fact I am not sure of the unit of main’s container width in the media-query style. Here’s the CSS design I want to achieve. How can I achieve this in the media-query styles?

[image: The design I intend to achieve]

Also, this is my code.

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BASE STYLES
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

:root {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
}

img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 81%) ;
}

.profile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2px;
}

main > div {
    padding-left: 2.3em; 
    padding-right: 4em;
    border-radius: 0.7em; 
}




p.second {
    font-size: 1.04rem;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END OF BASE STYLES
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


main {
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 900px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 1.6em;
    margin: 0 auto;      
}

div.first {
    background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
    background-image: url('images/bg-pattern-quotation.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 100% bottom 100%;
}

.daniel dl, .jonathan dl{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
}

.daniel dd, .jonathan dd{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
p.first {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.daniel.first, .jonathan.first {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

.profile {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.profile ~ .first {
    margin: 1em 0 1.2em;
}

.daniel.second, .jonathan.second {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    opacity: 0.7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
}

.profile ~ .second {
    opacity: 0.7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 2.2em;
}

div.second {
    background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
}

div.third, div.fifth {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.jeanette dl, .kira dl {
    color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
}
.jeanette dd, .kira dd {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.jeanette.first, .kira.first {
    color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
}

.jeanette.second, .kira.second {
    color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
    opacity: 0.7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
}

div.fourth {
    background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
}

.patrick dl {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

.patrick dd {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.patrick.first {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

.patrick.second {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    opacity: 0.7;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------
Media Query Styles
----------------------------------------------------------*/

@media(min-width: 955px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    main {
        grid-template-areas: 
            "first first second fifth"
            "third fourth fourth fifth";
        gap: 1.6em;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
        max-width: 70%;
    }

    div.first {
        grid-area: first;
    }

    div.second {
        grid-area: second;
    }

    div.third {
        grid-area: third;
    }

    div.fourth {
        grid-area: fourth;
    }
    div.fifth {
        grid-area: fifth;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Testimonial Grid </title>


</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">
  <div class="first">

  <div class="daniel profile">
  <img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="daniel image">

  <dl>
  <dt>Daniel Clifford</dt>
  <dd>Verified Graduate</dd>
  </dl>

  </div>

  <p class="daniel first">I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so, 
  in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every penny’s worth.</p>

  <p class="daniel second">“I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a 
  transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up 
  for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter. 
  The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing 
  the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”</p>
  </div>

  <div class="second">

  <div class="jonathan profile">
  <img src="images/image-jonathan.jpg" alt="jonathan image">

  <dl>
  <dt>Jonathan Walters</dt>
  <dd>Verified Graduate</dd>
  </dl>

  </div>

  <p class="jonathan first">The team was very supportive and kept me motivated</p>

  <p class="jonathan second">“ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer 
  for a big company. This was one of the best investments I’ve made in myself. ”</p>
  </div>

  <div class="third">

  <div class="jeanette profile">
  <img src="images/image-jeanette.jpg" alt="jeanette image">

  <dl>
  <dt>Jeanette Harmon</dt>
  <dd>Verified Graduate</dd>
  </dl>
  </div>

  <p class="jeanette first">An overall wonderful and rewarding experience</p>

  <p class="jeanette second"> Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living 
  while doing something I love.”</p>
  </div>

  <div class="fourth">
  <div class="patrick profile">
  <img src="images/image-patrick.jpg" alt="patrick image">

  <dl>
  <dt>Patrick Abrams</dt>
  <dd>Verified Graduate</dd>
  </dl>
  </div>

  <p class="patrick first">Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and 
  learning from their experiences was easy</p>

  <p class="patrick second">“ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program 
  gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable 
  junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You will get the personal attention you need from 
  an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”</p>
  </div>

  <div class="fifth">
  <div class="kira profile">
  <img src="images/image-kira.jpg" alt="kira image">
  
  <dl>
  <dt>Kira Whittle</dt>
  <dd>Verified Graduate</dd>
  </dl>
  </div>

  <p class="kira first">Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!</p>

  <p class="kira second">“ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from 
  professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former 
  student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about the program. The entire curriculum and staff 
  did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team 
  project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that no tutorial 
  could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent 
  experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 
  100% recommend! ”</p>
  </div>

  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good attempt at a question, but it needs improvement. Please edit your question to improve its clarity. In particular, you need to add details on the differences between the results your code is giving (as illustrated in your snippet) and the behaviour you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a screenshot of your snippet being viewed in a full page. It seems to match the design pretty well. You need to edit your question to explain more clearly the ways in which the page produced by your code does not match your expectations or the design.

[image: screenshot]